# Add global item to swagger.json when using Swashbuckle

Tags: asp.net-core, swashbuckle

I'm using Swashbuckle to generate a swagger file which I am then uploading to Google Endpoints.

Google Endpoints requires these two parms (host and x-google-backend)

```
"host": "XXXX-ax7nuhuyua-uc.a.run.app",
"x-google-backend": {
    "address": "https://YYYY-dev-ax7nuhuyua-uc.a.run.app",
    "protocol": "h2"
},
```

These need to be added at the same level as swagger, info, paths

Can someone tell me how to extend the swagger file that's generated by Swashbuckle to include these global params?

Using ASPNET Core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can add to the `Extensions` variable directly in `Startup.cs` in `SwaggerDoc`.

```
services
    .AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
        {
            // Any other properties

            Extensions = new Dictionary<string, IOpenApiExtension>
            {
                {
                    "x-google-backend", new OpenApiObject
                    {
                        {"address", new OpenApiString("https://YYYY-dev-ax7nuhuyua-uc.a.run.app")},
                        {"protocol", new OpenApiString("h2")}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "host", new OpenApiString("XXXX-ax7nuhuyua-uc.a.run.app")
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: That's it .. thank you, it's this notion of "Extensions" that I was not familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by creating an operation filter like the following:

```
    public class AddParameterOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            // add your parameters here
            operation.Parameters.Add(new OpenApiParameter());
        }
    }
```

In your Startup.cs you can add this filter to the swagger DI pipeline using the following:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
  options.OperationFilter<AddParameterOperationFilter>();
});
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this for this specific problem but I have used operation filters for customizing swagger docs.

Comment: mm .. perhaps I'm missing something here, but this seems like it would be the correct thing to do if I was wanting to add a parameter to each of the methods/operations. This Apply method gets called for every method I expose and the context is the method itself. The IDocumentFilter seems more like what I want, but I can't quite figure out how to use it to add these news global items.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that’s what you were looking for. My bad